# Cycle through a variable range with another variable

Tags: python-3.x, python-itertools

I need to loop through 2 variables and cycle through 1 variable from 2 variables (whichever is bigger) until the range of the 2nd (longest) last.
For example

```
x = 5 #input by user
y = 8 #input by user

for x_val, y_val in itertools.zip_longest(range(x), range(y), fillvalue='-'):
    print(x_val)
    print(y_val)
```

Expected output

```
0
0
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
0
5
1
6
2
7
```

tried

```
x = 5
x_cyc = itertools.cycle(range(x))
y = 8

for x_val, y_val in itertools.zip_longest(range(x), x_cyc):
    print(x_val)
    print(y_val)
```

but that didn't make much sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you dont need zip longest, you create an infinite cycle for the smaller of the two numbers and then normal range for the larger number. this way the min range will be infinite and max range will be the finite range.

You can simply use normal zip to go through them till you reach the end of the non infinite range.

```py
from itertools import cycle
x = 8
y = 5
min_range = cycle(range(min(x, y)))
max_range = range(max(x, y))

for x_val, y_val in zip(min_range, max_range):
    print(x_val)
    print(y_val)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
0
0
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
0
5
1
6
2
7
```

**UPDATE BASED ON COMMENTS**

Now the x_val and y_val are bound to the x and y range and the lowest of x or y ints will be cycled in range.

```py
from itertools import cycle

x = 8
y = 5
x_range = range(x)
y_range = range(y)
if x > y:
    y_range = cycle(y_range)
elif y > x:
    x_range = cycle(x_range)

for x_val, y_val in zip(x_range, y_range):
    print(x_val)
    print(y_val)
```

Note that the output will now differ when x is greater than y or when y is greater than x since x will always output first.

**OUTPUT x=2, y=3**

```
0
0
1
1
0
2
```

**OUTPUT x=3 y=2**

```
0
0
1
1
2
0
```

Comment: Not completely what the OP requires.  Whichever is the longest sequence.  The second was used as an example, but it could be the first one

Comment: Why ranging from 1? Look at the expected output

Comment: The OP in the original post had it ranging from 1

Comment: @Pynchia sorry, I edited the code. In the original it was ranging from 1.

Comment: @Pynchia I have updated the code to work to cycle the smallest number of the two so it wont matter which order the numbers are in

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Thanks. Is there any way I can justify between x_val and y_val. I need to know which is ranging for which variable as I need them for more functionality in the loop. I want x_val to range for x and y_val to range for y strictly.

Comment: oh gosh, ever changing requirements......hehe. No probs. i have added an updated code at the bottom of my answer which will ensure x_val is bound to x_range and y_val bound to y_range. But also ensure to cycle the shortest of the two ranges